# BasicDataSource configured in spring vs Weblogic datasource

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, datasource

1. BasicDataSource configured in spring
2. Weblogic datasource

which implementation is better in terms of

1. Stability
2. Performance
3. scalability
4. Online Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't even consider using `BasicDataSource` when using WebLogic Server, its connection pool just rocks:

- it's extremely stable, rock solid (one of the top reasons to use it);
- it has a great set of features (can't think of any missing one);
- it performs very well, no dead lock issues;
- it's clusterable;
- the administration, configuration are easy and they can be automated with WLST;
- monitoring is easy (via JMX);
- it's well documented;
- it's **supported** by BEA.

For me, this is a no match.

PS: Of course, this answer applies when running **inside WebLogic** (which is assumed since the question is about **WebLogic connection pool**). In your IDE or in a testing context, use whatever you want, e.g. no connection pool at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler to test and work with Apache's BasicDatasource from your IDE, since you only need the datasource jar file in your classpath. It's not necessary to deploy to an application container.

`com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` and the datasource that's bundled with the [tcServer](http://www.springsource.com/products/tcserver) is also highly scalable.

The BasicDatasource and the ComboPooledDataSource also gives you the ability to use the same datasource in all environments and it's not coupled to the application container.

And at least the datasource that's bundled with the tcServer is supported by SpringSource.

The ComboPooledDataSource and the Spring alternative are also easy to manage and monitor with JMX.

On the other side, if you're using XA transactions and Weblogic's JTA transaction manager, then you should also use WebLogic's datasource.